# PHP Random including the mentioned "text" on top 1 to 5 statements

Tags: php

I been trying to add the mentioned "text" in my web crawler extracted statements.

**php web crawler ::**

```
<?php
    function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
    $returned_content = get_data('http://www.usmle-forums.com/usmle-step-1-forum/');
    $first_step = explode( '<tbody id="threadbits_forum_26"' , $returned_content );
    $second_step = explode('</tbody>', $first_step[1]);
    $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[0]);
    // print_r($third_step);
    foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    $child_first = explode( '<td class="alt1"' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
    $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
    $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
    $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";
?>
    <li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">
        <span class="item_new">text</span><?php echo $final?>
    </li>
<?php
    if($key==10){
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

now i been trying to insert the "text" mentioned in span tag to be added randomly on the first five statements extracted by the web crawler.

so whenever user refreshes the page, the "text" in span tag should shuffle in between top 5 statements.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: This question needs additional clarity.  What have you attempted?  What is the current output?  What is the intended output?  What is working properly?  What is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
<?php
  function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }
  $returned_content = get_data('http://www.usmle-forums.com/usmle-step-1-forum/');
  $first_step = explode( '<tbody id="threadbits_forum_26"' , $returned_content );
  $second_step = explode('</tbody>', $first_step[1]);
  $third_step = explode('<tr>', $second_step[0]);
  // print_r($third_step);
  foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    $child_first = explode( '<td class="alt1"' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</td>' , $child_first[1] );
    $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
    $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
    $final = "<a href=".$child_fourth[0]."</a></br>";

    echo '<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">';
    if($key < 5 && rand(0,1) == 1) {
      echo '<span class="item_new">YOUR TEXT </span>';
    }

    echo $final;
    echo '</li>';

    if($key==10) {
      break;
    }

  }
?>
```

It adds "YOUR TEXT" randomly to the first five lines.

Output:

```
YOUR TEXT
1 Attachment(s)
Pass Your Step 1 Exam - 100% Guaranteed!
USMLE Step 1 Live prep/Boot Camp in Chicago
YOUR TEXT  1 Attachment(s)
Picmonic for Medicine
Increase Your Step 1 Score Through 1-on-1 Online Tutoring
Low Score on Step 1?
step 1 tutoring
Frustrated USMLE taker mom.
Looking for a tutor
```

Comment: dude, thats exactly what i needed, but this code isn't working.. it shows the "text" for all 10 statements..

Comment: @harishk: For me it works fine. I see the text "text" appended to the first five lines randomly. Can you update your question with an example of the expected result? I have also updated the solution I posted.